# Vlad's pool and how it works against DOT

Tags: league-of-legends

Does vlad pool stop the damage from over time effects like ignite and malz dot?

Comment: That would be rediclously OP if it did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it only makes you untargetable, so if you pool at low health, you could die from the DoT.

Here's a quote from the LoL Wiki on it:

> Vladimir is still affected by damage over time effects (like Ignite and Swain's Torment) while going into Sanguine Pool.

Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vladimir_the_Crimson_Reaper/Ability_Details

Comment: Remember that the pool costs health, making it more likely to die if pooling while under the effects of a DoT.